# How do I add a header with data to a QTableWidget in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtablewidget, qheaderview

I'm still learning Qt and I am indebted to the SO community for providing me with great, very timely answers to my Qt questions. Thank you.

I'm quite confused on the idea of adding a header to a `QTableWidget`. What I'd like to do is have a table that contains information about team members. Each `row` for a member should contain his first and last name, each in its own cell, an email address in one cell, and office in the other cell. I'd to have a `header` above these columns to name them as appropriate.

I'm trying to start off easy and get just the header to display "Last" (as in last name). Here is my code.

```
int column = m_ui->teamTableWidget->columnCount();
m_ui->teamTableWidget->setColumnCount(column+1);
QString* qq = new QString("Last");
m_ui->teamTableWidget->horizontalHeader()->model()->setHeaderData(0, 
Qt::Horizontal, QVariant(QVariant::String, &qq));
```

My table gets rendered corretly, but the header doesn't contain what I would expect. It contains 1 cell that contains the text "1".

I am obviously doing something very silly here that is wrong, but i am lost. I keep pouring over the documentation, finding nothing.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: If that was the actual answer to your problem, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the request of the person who steered me toward the right place, I am posting the way I accomplished this as an answer and I am accepting it.

```
    m_ui->teamTableWidget->setColumnCount(m_ui->teamTableWidget->columnCount()+1);
    QTableWidgetItem* qtwi = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("Last"),QTableWidgetItem::Type);
    m_ui->teamTableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0,qtwi);
```

Answer (score 12):

The easiest solution is `setHorizontalHeaderLabels(myListOfHeaderLabels)`.

Comment: I actually meant to link to `QTableWidget::setHorizontalHeaderLabels`. Same method name, same functionality.

Answer (score 5):

I see one potential problem, and also an easier way to do this.

First, the problem:

```
QString* qq = new QString("Last"); // <- qq is a pointer to a string.
m_ui->teamTableWidget->horizontalHeader()->model()->setHeaderData(0, 
    Qt::Horizontal, 
    QVariant(QVariant::String, &qq)); // <- You take the address of a pointer, or create a handle.
```

I think you want to do this instead:

```
QString* qq = new QString("Last");
m_ui->teamTableWidget->horizontalHeader()->model()->setHeaderData(0, 
    Qt::Horizontal, QVariant(QVariant::String, *qq));
```

Now, the easier way to set the data for a header item:

```
m_ui->teamTableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem( 0 )->setText( "Last" );
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit in the question to see how I solved it. Your help got me there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

For posterity:

The default implimentations of setHeaderData() and headerData() in QAbstractItemModel do not do anything. You can (should?) (re)impliment headerData() in order to return useful a label.